# AutoScroll to reposition textinput above keyboard

Tags: android, python, kivy

In the given example , if the user presses enter or reaches a certain number of characters per line , the TextInput adds a new line . After a certain amount of new lines added the TextInput will go behind the Button making the new lines not viewable. I want the ScrollView to auto-scroll so that the last line of the TextInput will always be above the Button.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_string("""
<MainLayout>:
    ScrollView:
        id: sv
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: root.height  + tti1.height - tti1.line_height * 3/2
            TabTextInput:
                id: tti1
                font_size: 25
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.line_height*3/2
                y: root.height - self.line_height * 3/2
    Button:
        id: button_id
        size_hint_y: .5
        text: 'Keyboard'
        font_size: 120
        color: 0,0,0,1
""")

class TabTextInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TabTextInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        key, key_str = keycode
        if key is not 8:
            if key is 13 or self.cursor_col == 20:
                self.insert_text('\n')
                self.add_line()
                return False
        else:
            if self.cursor_col==0 and self.cursor_row>0:
                self.remove_line()
        return super(TabTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)

    def add_line(self):
        self.height += self.line_height

    def remove_line(self):
        self.height -= self.line_height

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to name your ScrollView so you can reference to it. For example if you called it 'scrollview' the code should look like this:

```
def add_line(self):
    self.height += self.line_height
    scrollview.scroll_y=0
```

However you will see this is not working a 100% properly, the scroll_y attribute of ScrollView gives you the only control over scrolling. That's what the documentation says about it:

"Y scrolling value, between 0 and 1. If 0, the content’s bottom side will touch the bottom side of the ScrollView. If 1, the content’s top side will touch the top side."